# Netty 4 HttpContentCompressor file region

Tags: encoding, netty, zero-copy

I'm attempting to send a file to the response and support encoding. The code is mostly copied from one of the examples in the Netty github.

```
        ChannelFuture flushFuture;
        if (context.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class) == null) {
            // SSL not enabled - can use zero-copy file transfer.
            context.write(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, getLength()), context.newProgressivePromise());
            flushFuture = context.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT);
        } else {
            // SSL enabled - cannot use zero-copy file transfer.
            try {
                // HttpChunkedInput will write the end marker (LastHttpContent) for us.
                flushFuture = context.writeAndFlush(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, getLength(), 8192)),
                        context.newProgressivePromise());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new CustomizableResponseTypeException("Could not read file", e);
            }
        }
```

When the server is using SSL, all works well. When SSL is not being used, the zero-copy file transfer is being done and the encoding doesn't produce the correct output.

I've ready this [blog post](http://andreas.haufler.info/2014/01/making-http-content-compression-work-in.html) that seems to indicate what I'm trying to do could work, however I don't understand what part of the example code could cause it to work. Any tips or help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's not possible. The solution is to only use zero-copy for files that are small or not compressible.

Comment: Zerocopy essentially bypasses user-space, so it makes sense that if you want to compress on-the-fly, you can't use it.